# Difference between simple import statement and System.import in ES6 Module Loader

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, ecmascript-harmony, es6-module-loader

Is anybody able to explain the difference between a simple `import` and a `System.import` statement of the ES6 Module Loader (or Polyfills like System.js, Webpack etc.)

Something like

```
System.import('https://code.jquery.com/jquery.js').then();
```

seems to be possible, as well as a simple

```
 import 'jquery';
```

Is `System.import` the only possibility to have a callback after the import statement?

Comment: They have just different use cases. `System.import` allows you to load modules dynamically. `import` does not allow that but doesn't require you to use callbacks.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use the System.import inside `<script>` tags where import aren't supported, and you can also load modules conditionally.

So you can programmatically import a module, via an API based on ES6 promises, in addition of the declarative syntax for working with modules that is the ES6 import.

Comment: < script > tags, sorry (inside your index.html or someName.html file)